# How to add box-shadow to the right of the div element using css?

Tags: html, css

i have a div element and i want to add the box-shadow only to the rightside of the div element.

below is my code,

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child_divs"> //want boxshadow to the right of this div
        <span>first</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child_divs">
        <span>second</span>
    </div>
</div>


.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 48px;
    & > :first-child {
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); //this adds boxshadow to right          and bottom of div_one.
    }
}

.child_divs {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 16px 0 0 16px;
    border-radius: 0 8px 0 0;
}
```

This adds box-shadow to right and bottom of first child div.i want it only to the right side. below is how it looks with above code.

[image]

As seen from above picture, the one marked in red. i dont want that bottom boxshadow for the first child div. how can i fix this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set box-shadow here

https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

If you got the one which you like ,simply just copy the code and apply it on element :)

Comment: thanks i have tried using it. but it gives me thicker box shadows...for my example i have tried box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); and this add boxshadow for the top bottom and right of the div element.